# Ubuntu 21.10 set AltGr + u -> ü

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 21.10

I'm trying to change the keyboard, so that by entering AltGr (Right Alt) + u the key ü appears.

Added /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us

key  {        [         u,    U, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis               ]       };

Ubuntu seems to recognize it:

[image]

But if pressing right alt and u nothing happens. Any idea what is missing? I tried to play around with the compose key settings but it didn't help.

Comment: Enabling the US International layout variant with dead keys it's much easier (and don't break other things).

Comment: Maybe you have to configure right alt to send Alt Gr?

Comment: @Bodo Any idea how to enable it ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the steps taken to set the `Compose` key. I have the `Compose` key set (in 20.04) which works by latching the key presses in sequence so that by pressing `Compose` then `u` then `"` I can produce ü

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Found a solution using
https://github.com/SnakeJesus/Umlaute-on-US-layout
Didn't touch the compose key in any way

Comment: @MichaelRazum: Would you mind submitting the solution as an answer? It's worth mentioning that the missing piece was that you previously hadn't defined AltGr as the key for accessing 3rd level symbols.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that file shouldn't be modified by the user, could be overwritten any time upon update, and almost certainly upon upgrade. A new file should be created instead, probably in `/etc/X11/xkb/symbols`, but I admit it will likely raise a bunch of other questions.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was using

github.com/SnakeJesus/Umlaute-on-US-layout

It seems that it is also necessary to define the AltGr key (see Gunnar Hjalmarsson comment):

include "level3(ralt_switch)"

Answer (score 0):

x11/xmodmap does not work with wayland. Wayland uses xkb

So there are 2 ways

### 1. Use x11/xmodmap

#### First: Set ubuntu on x11 on startup-login

On the login choose 'x11' instead of 'wayland'. You can do it by  clicking on the bottom-right-button while login in.

#### Show which keyboard-layout:

If `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` shows only

```
...
layout: us
...
```

changes on the .Xmodmap have no effects.

#### set the correct international keyboard

```
setxkbmap -layout 'us(intl)'
```

must result in

```
setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us(intl)
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us(intl)+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(intl)+inet(evdev)"       };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

#### Set .Xmodmap

Example:

3. use the a modified .Xmodmap

```
! clear lock
keycode   8 =
keycode   9 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
keycode  10 = 1 exclam 1 exclam
keycode  11 = 2 at 2 at
keycode  12 = 3 numbersign 3 numbersign
keycode  13 = 4 dollar 4 dollar
keycode  14 = 5 percent 5 percent
keycode  15 = 6 asciicircum 6 asciicircum
keycode  16 = 7 ampersand 7 ampersand
keycode  17 = 8 asterisk 8 asterisk threequarters dead_ogonek threequarters
keycode  18 = 9 parenleft 9 parenleft
keycode  19 = 0 parenright 0 parenright
keycode  20 = minus underscore minus underscore
keycode  21 = equal plus equal plus
keycode  22 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace
keycode  23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  24 = q Q q Q
keycode  25 = w W w W
keycode  26 = e E e E EuroSign
keycode  27 = r R r R registered
keycode  28 = t T t T
keycode  29 = y Y y Y
keycode  30 = u U u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode  31 = i I i I
keycode  32 = o O o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode  33 = p P p P
keycode  34 = bracketleft braceleft bracketleft braceleft
keycode  35 = bracketright braceright bracketright braceright
keycode  36 = Return NoSymbol Return
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode  38 = a A a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode  39 = s S s S ssharp section
keycode  40 = d D d D
keycode  41 = f F f F
keycode  42 = g G g G
keycode  43 = h H h H
keycode  44 = j J j J
keycode  45 = k K k K
keycode  46 = l L l L
keycode  47 = semicolon colon semicolon
keycode  48 = apostrophe quotedbl apostrophe quotedbl
keycode  49 = grave asciitilde grave asciitilde
keycode  50 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L
keycode  51 = backslash bar backslash bar
keycode  52 = z Z z Z
keycode  53 = x X x X
keycode  54 = c C c C
keycode  55 = v V v V
keycode  56 = b B b B
keycode  57 = n N n N
keycode  58 = m M m M
keycode  59 = comma less comma less
keycode  60 = period greater period greater
keycode  61 = slash question slash question
keycode  62 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R
keycode  63 = KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply XF86ClearGrab
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode  65 = space NoSymbol space
keycode  66 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
! keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
keycode  67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
keycode  68 = F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 XF86Switch_VT_2
keycode  69 = F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 XF86Switch_VT_3
keycode  70 = F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4
keycode  71 = F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5
keycode  72 = F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 XF86Switch_VT_6
keycode  73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7
keycode  74 = F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 XF86Switch_VT_8
keycode  75 = F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 XF86Switch_VT_9
keycode  76 = F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10
keycode  77 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock
keycode  78 = Scroll_Lock NoSymbol Scroll_Lock
keycode  79 = KP_Home KP_7 KP_Home KP_7
keycode  80 = KP_Up KP_8 KP_Up KP_8
keycode  81 = KP_Prior KP_9 KP_Prior KP_9
keycode  82 = KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract XF86Prev_VMode
keycode  83 = KP_Left KP_4 KP_Left KP_4
keycode  84 = KP_Begin KP_5 KP_Begin KP_5
keycode  85 = KP_Right KP_6 KP_Right KP_6
keycode  86 = KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add XF86Next_VMode
keycode  87 = KP_End KP_1 KP_End KP_1
keycode  88 = KP_Down KP_2 KP_Down KP_2
keycode  89 = KP_Next KP_3 KP_Next KP_3
keycode  90 = KP_Insert KP_0 KP_Insert KP_0
keycode  91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Decimal
keycode  92 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode  93 =
keycode  94 = Escape NoSymbol Escape NoSymbol
keycode  95 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
keycode  96 = F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12
keycode  97 =
keycode  98 = Katakana NoSymbol Katakana
keycode  99 = Hiragana NoSymbol Hiragana
keycode 100 = Henkan_Mode NoSymbol Henkan_Mode
keycode 101 = Hiragana_Katakana NoSymbol Hiragana_Katakana
keycode 102 = Muhenkan NoSymbol Muhenkan
keycode 103 =
keycode 104 = KP_Enter NoSymbol KP_Enter
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 106 = KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide XF86Ungrab
keycode 107 = Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode 109 = Linefeed NoSymbol Linefeed
keycode 110 = Home NoSymbol Home
keycode 111 = Up NoSymbol Up
keycode 112 = Prior NoSymbol Prior
keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol Left
keycode 114 = Right NoSymbol Right
keycode 115 = End NoSymbol End
keycode 116 = Down NoSymbol Down
keycode 117 = Next NoSymbol Next
keycode 118 = Insert NoSymbol Insert
keycode 119 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
keycode 120 =
keycode 121 = XF86AudioMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMute
keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume
keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume
keycode 124 = XF86PowerOff NoSymbol XF86PowerOff
keycode 125 = KP_Equal NoSymbol KP_Equal
keycode 126 = plusminus NoSymbol plusminus
keycode 127 = Pause Break Pause Break
keycode 128 = XF86LaunchA NoSymbol XF86LaunchA
keycode 129 = KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal
keycode 130 = Hangul NoSymbol Hangul
keycode 131 = Hangul_Hanja NoSymbol Hangul_Hanja
```

#### load the .Xmodmap

```
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

### 2. config it with wayland

(didn't test in by myself)

keyboard cargo
xremap is a key remapper for Linux. Unlike xmodmap, it supports app-specific remapping and Wayland.

- k0kubun/xremap: Dynamic key remapper for X11 and Wayland
  https://github.com/k0kubun/xremap